# Moved all home directories to different folder?

Tags: shell, unix, move

Ok this is embarrassing!! I wanted to move remote folder from downloads on to /var/www/html directory !! So I used the following command with sudo

```
    mv /Downloads/remote /var/www/html/remote
```

And messed up entire file system !! All my home folders which includes downloads,  folders and data on  desktop everything is moved in /var/www/html/remote and no application or files seems to open !! The only thing that opens is the terminal !! How can I fix this please help !!

Comment: Are you sure this is the only command you run? It can't explain what you see. You may just try `sudo mv /var/www/html/remote/<your_user_name> /home/` to reverse. Otherwise if `<your_user_name>` isn't in `/var/www/html/remote/`, do a `sudo cp -rp /var/www/html/remote/<your_user_name>/* /home/<your_user_name>/`, then remove manually what shouldn't be in `remote` and what shouldn't be in `/home/<your_user_name>/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to try to reverse it:

```
sudo mv /var/www/html/remote/<your_user_name> /home/
```

Otherwise if `<your_user_name>` isn't in `/var/www/html/remote/`, do a:

```
sudo cp -rp /var/www/html/remote/<your_user_name>/* /home/<your_user_name>/
```

then remove manually what shouldn't be in directory `remote` and what shouldn't be in directory  `/home/<your_user_name>/`...

Comment: Thanks a ton !! The first solution worked

Comment: Lucky you, it will avoid the tedious manual part :)

Comment: Ywa all thanks to u